# PHP Compare array CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 tables, it is Request_Book and Gudang

Table Request_Book

```
title       | orderQuantity
Harry putra | 12
Guardion    | 3
```

Table Gudang

```
title        | Quantity
Harry putra  | 4
Ben 7        | 2
```

I have several conditions:

- Quantity of Gudang must be greater than orderQuantity
- Title of Request_Book must be less than or same with title on Gudang

and the in my controller, i code like this:

```
$cekBookRequest = $this->db->select("title, orderQuantity")
                           ->get('request_book')->result_array();

$cekGudang = $this->db->select("title, quantity")
                      ->get('stock_summary_warehouse')->result_array();

$result = $this->cek_values($cekBookRequest, $cekGudang);
var_dump($result);
```

And here is my comparison array:

```
function cek_values($arrayA, $arrayB) {
   sort($arrayA);
   sort($arrayB);
   return $arrayA == $arrayB;
}
```

My comparison array only check a title is same or not in both tables. My expectation is
if Request_Book have

```
title       | orderQuantity
Harry putra | 2
Ben 7       | 2
```

that will return **true** or just if Request_Book

```
title       | orderQuantity
Harry putra | 2
```

that also return **true**

In a first tables above will return **false** because title Guardion in Gudang is not exist and Harry putra quantity is 12. How to check and compare title and quantity in arrays on cek_values function?

Answer (score 0):

Honnestly, I did not understand the conditions you wanted...
Nevertheless, I think that you should modify your arrays. Since you only have two piece of information, you should use key => value. I mean :

1. Foreach to modify arrays :

   ```
   foreach ($arrayA as $row) {
    $book[row['title']] = row['OrderQuantity'];
   }
   foreach ($arrayB as $row2) {
    $gudang[row2['title']] = row2['Quantity'];
   }
   ```
2. Then use PHP functions
   You have several functions to sort key and values : http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
3. You can compare by PHP functions.

Use foreach to compare arrays, or array_diff(), it shall help. Let me know.